# Building a Blog Using Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've seen websites whose blog was created with Meteor (I believe Meteor.com's is). How are people doing it? I can create a page with a form with fields for a title and text, but I can't seem to make the logical leap into hiding that form. As it stands, it's sitting on the page with the published articles which obviously isn't ideal.

Thanks for your thoughts!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check this awesome package

https://github.com/Differential/meteor-blog.

I've built [www.meteorsnippets.com](http://www.meteorsnippets.com) and deployed in couple of hours using this package

Docs can be found here http://github.differential.com/meteor-blog/

all you need to do is

add the package

```
meteor add ryw:blog
```

and add roles for admins and authors

```
Blog.config
    adminRole: 'blogAdmin'
    authorRole: 'blogAuthor'
```

In users collection add roles field to user with the above roles

```
"roles": ["blogAdmin"]
```

that's it, it works out of the box.

Comment: Welcome, If it answers your question accept it as answer